# Can an image have a custom default shm-size?

Tags: docker

I have a container which must be run with a /dev/shm larger than the default 64Mb.  It works to run it like this:

```
docker run --shm-size=1G my-container
```

It is inconvenient though to have to provide the 'shm-size' argument every time, and easily missed for someone not familiar with the container.  It would be nice if the container itself could have a custom default shm size.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Can an image have a custom default shm-size?

**A:** Short answer, **no**.

It is not possible because you can only open shared memory during runtime.

**Q:**
It is inconvenient though to have to provide the 'shm-size' argument every time, and easily missed for someone not familiar with the container.

**A:** I see your problem.

Maybe you can use `docker-labels`. Add a key-value pair label like `shm-size=1G` to your `docker images`.

Then create a simple script to do a `docker inspect`, read the key-value pair off the image and then do the usual `docker run --shm-size=read_value`.

**Docker label:**

> The LABEL instruction adds metadata to an image. A LABEL is a key-value pair. To include spaces within a LABEL value, use quotes and backslashes as you would in command-line parsing. A few usage examples:

**See**:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label

Answer (score 2):

Starting with docker 17.04 you can use --default-shm-size option. But of course it will have global effect

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#17040-ce-2017-04-05

Answer (score 1):

No.  And I think it shouldn't for these reasons:

- A lot of other options should be baked in too.  But the less code, the better.
- This option is system specific.  I don't know if the Windows containers have this partition.
- The docker client is **runc** (which is the client container for the Open Container Initiative that Docker is contributing to).

What you can do, however, is to check in the entrypoint script the size of the /dev/shm partition and loudly refuse to run.